# Wrapping Background Colors Around Candles Using Pine-Script v4 (Tradingview)

Tags: background-color, word-wrap, pine-script

I am attempting to create an indicator which will have the background colors only wrapping the candles, leaving the rest of the chart white or black. 
I am unable to find functionality for this. Is it possible even with the v4 update?
Thanks all,

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Consider editing your title to include the language/environment and version you're working in.  I had to check the tags to assume it's Pine Script but you want that in the title to both make it easier for readers and get more attention from those who could help.

Comment: See https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#fun_bgcolor

Comment: Hey thanks! I’ll do just that 